# Stop accordion from expanding when More button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

When the **More** button is clicked, it should NOT expand and collapse.

[image]

If the accordion initial state is open, it must stay open even if button is clicked, if initial state is collapsed then after the more button the accordion should not expand.

**This means clicking the more button should not have any effect on the accordion.**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .accordion {
            margin: 30px;
        }

        .accordion-button.collapsed {
            border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid
        }

        .accordion-body {
            border-left: #673ab744 1px solid;
            border-bottom: #673ab744 1px solid;
            border-right: #673ab744 1px solid
        }

        .accordion-button {
            display: inline !important
        }

        .flx-row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .card-header-custom {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0">

    <div class="card accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">

                    <div class="flx-row">
                        <div>
                            Hello World
                        </div>
                        <div id="abc">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-secondary">Desc goes here</span>
                </button>


            </h2>
            <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                    Accordion Item #2
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
        <div class="as-console"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".wdelete")
            .off()
            .on('click', function(event) {
                if (confirm(`Are you sure to delete the workflow ${$(this).prev().parent().prev().val()}?`) == true) {
                    $(this)
                        .closest('.accordion-item')
                        .remove();
                }
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
            
            
            $("#abc").html(`<div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> More </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end" style="">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Click me</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hello me</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item tdelete" href="#">Justify me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>`)

            
    </script>

    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
        <div class="as-console"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
        <div class="as-console"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please check my below answer which I have mentioned with the working link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you have a button that triggers the accordion and inside that button you have your `div` "More". So when you click the "More" it also triggers the accordion. You need to put your "More" button outside the first accordion button.

Also add this `.accordion-button.collapsed + div#abc` to your CSS at line 6.

Something like this:

```js
$(".wdelete")
  .off()
  .on('click', function(event) {
    if (confirm(`Are you sure to delete the workflow ${$(this).prev().parent().prev().val()}?`) == true) {
      $(this)
        .closest('.accordion-item')
        .remove();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });


$("#abc").html(`<div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> More </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end" style="">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Click me</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hello me</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item tdelete" href="#">Justify me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>`)
```

```css
.accordion {
  margin: 30px;
}

.accordion-button.collapsed,
.accordion-button.collapsed + div#abc {
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
}

.accordion-body {
  border-left: #673ab744 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #673ab744 1px solid;
  border-right: #673ab744 1px solid;
}

.accordion-button {
  display: inline !important;
}

.flx-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card-header-custom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0">

<div class="card accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <div class="flx-row">

        <!-- This block is your button that triggers the first accordion, notice the "data-bs-target" -->
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
          <div>Hello World</div>
          <span class="text-secondary">Desc goes here</span>
        </button>

        <!-- This is where your "More" button gets rendered, outside of <button> -->
        <div id="abc"></div>

      </div>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="as-console-wrapper">
  <div class="as-console"></div>
</div>


<div class="as-console-wrapper">
  <div class="as-console"></div>
</div>
<div class="as-console-wrapper">
  <div class="as-console"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I find that your More dropdown is inserted in the accordion button due to which you find the issue of accordion open/close when more dropdown get clicked.

In the below link, I have modified your code little bit where I have adjusted HTML, CSS and added 2 lines of jQuery which will be global for your HTML structure. Please refer below link:
```

[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/jc2gzv5L/)

Comment: Please let me know if you find any issues.